# If $f$ is finite almost everywhere and $E$ is of finite Lebesgue measure, then f is "almost" bounded

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

If a real measurable function $f : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\ \cup \{\infty\}$ is finite almost everywhere (i.e. $f^{-1}(\{\infty\})$ has measure zero) and $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is of finite Lebesgue measure, then $\forall \varepsilon > 0\ \exists\ F \subset E$ with $|E \setminus F| \leq \varepsilon$ and $f$ bounded in $F$.

I supposed that no such $F$ exists, and I tried to prove that $f = \infty$ in a set with positive measure, but without success. Any help? :)

Comment: What does "finite almost everywhere" mean here? Are you assuming that $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ and simply saying that $f^{-1}(\{\infty\})$ is null?

Comment: not null, but of measure zero. I'll edit the question though, I noticed it's not very clear.

Comment: Using the result of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1786113/can-the-unit-interval-be-the-disjoint-union-of-countably-many-super-dense-part) which I asked for the purpose, we can see that the assumption that $f$ is measurable is crucial. [Its answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1786128/14366) shows that, assuming the Axiom of Choice, $\mathbb R$ can be partitioned into continuum many sets $(X_t)_{t\in\mathbb R}$ such that every $X_t$ intersects every set of positive measure. Then let $f(x)=$the $t$ such that $x\in X_t$, and then $f$ is not bounded in any $F$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define $F_n=\{x\in E:|f(x)|> n\}$. Then $F_1\supset F_2\supset\cdots$ and 
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n=\{x\in E:|f(x)|=\infty\}$$

Since $E$ has finite measure, we can apply continuity from above to conclude that
$$ 0=|\{x\in E:|f(x)|=\infty\}|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|F_n|$$
Therefore given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $n$ such that $|F_n|<\varepsilon$, so the set $F=E\setminus F_n$ has the desired properties.

Comment: How do you know $|F_n|$ exists? It doesn't seem to be assumed that $f$ is measurable.

Comment: I suppose I assumed $f$ is measurable, because it's not clear how to interpret the statement that $f$ is finite a.e. otherwise.

Comment: Even if $f$ is not measurable, it still seems to make sense to ask whether $f^{-1}(\{\infty\})$ _happens to be_ a measurable set with measure $0$.

Comment: I guess. While OP should clarify, I'm reasonably confident that $f$ is measurable.

Comment: Thanks! The thing is that I don't know the real hypothesis of the question. I didn't even know if it was true. If f is measurable (I added it just now), then carmichael561 is right. I would suspect that if f is not measurable then the lemma doesn't hold....but working with non-measurable functions is hard for me, as I don't know many.

Comment: @SeñorBilly: Non-measurable functions are elusive things, difficult to construct. One needs to use the Axiom of Choice to show that they even exist.

Comment: Je, I know. That's why you aren't really capable of knowing what they do

Comment: @carmichael561: Is there a way to ensure that this set $F$ is closed?