# Can the unit interval be the disjoint union of countably many "super-dense" parts?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, axiom-of-choice

I'm curious about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1785345/if-f-is-finite-almost-everywhere-and-e-is-of-finite-lebesgue-measure-then-f) in the case where $f$ is not necessarily measurable.

I think what it comes down to is this:

> Is there an $\varepsilon<1$ and a partition of $[0,1]$ in countably many parts such that every subset of $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure at least $\varepsilon$ intersects infinitely many of the parts?

Clearly if the parts are measurable, then this is impossible.

Is it still necessarily impossible when we allow the parts to be wild?

Comment: Are you asking in ZFC, or if the axiom of choice is necessary? Because clearly if every set is measurable, this is impossible.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Yes, clearly -- as noted in the question already. Being curious, I suppose I'm asking both whether ZFC _proves_ that a partition with this property exists, and if not whether it is at least consistent that it exists.

Comment: Then I'm not entirely sure that the AC tag fits here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do much better. Assuming the axiom of choice, you can partition $\mathbb R$ into $2^{\aleph_0}$ disjoint parts, so that every uncountable Borel set intersects all of the parts.

The construction is a straightforward diagonalization, using the fact that there are only $2^{\aleph_0}$ uncountable closed sets, and each of those sets contains $2^{\aleph_0}$ points. It's the same idea as the construction of a [Bernstein set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set).

Let $\lambda$ be the smallest ordinal of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}.$ Let $\mathcal A$ be the set of all uncountable closed sets. Let $\mathcal A\times\mathbb R=\{(A_\alpha,t_\alpha):\alpha\lt\lambda\}.$ At step $\alpha,$ choose a point $x_\alpha\in A_\alpha\setminus\{t_\beta:\beta\lt\alpha\}.$ Finally, for each $t\in\mathbb R,$ let $X_t=\{x_\alpha:t_\alpha=t\}.$

The sets $X_t$ are pairwise disjoint, and every uncountable closed set intersects every $X_t.$ It follows that every Lebesgue measurable set of positive measure intersects every $X_t,$ since every set of positive measure contains a closed set of positive measure. In fact, every uncountable analytic set intersects every $X_t.$

Comment: But I'm not interested only in uncountable _closed_ sets -- for example, a suficiently large Smith-Volterra-Cantor set with the interval endpoints removed should intersect the parts too,

Comment: @HenningMakholm Well, every uncountable Borel (or analytic) set contains an uncountable closed set. Also, a Lebesgue-measurable set of positive measure contains a closed set with positive measure.

Comment: Can you expand on that straightforward construction, then?