Showing existence of measurable $F \subset E$ with $f$ bounded on $F$ where $f$ is measurable and $m(E) < \infty$
Given $f$ is a measurable function on $E$ and $m(E) < \infty$ with $f$ finite almost everywhere. I want to prove that for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have a measurable set $F \subset E$ such that $f$ is bounded on $F$ and $m(E \backslash F) < \epsilon$
My attempt: Using Luzin's theorem we know that there is a closed subset $F$ such that $m(E \backslash F)<\epsilon$ and $f$ is continuous on $F$. My problem is: What if the set $F$ is not bounded let's say $\mathbb{N}$ then $f(n)=n$ and it is unbounded. Even after Luzin's theorem I do not have compactness of $F$ and so how do I go about showing boundedness of $f$ on $F$.
Any ideas/suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answered here in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1785377
